# Query Database Periodically Automatically PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is a simple and straight forward question.I need to query my database every hour automatically. I know how to fetch the data, array them blah blah blah....... :-) the problem is I have to run the script manually. this is obviously not good programming practice and its boring. How do I do this automatically, do I need to run the script as a service? 
I am using Linux mint 9, php, mysql.

Comment: LOL, doing manually is just so wrong and I don't even think it can be achieved when you want to do it alone. You need to have same sleep! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add [cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) which will execute your PHP script every hour.

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
0 * * * * php script.php
```